# Migrating server from RHEL 5.5 to Centos 6.4 remotely

Tags: linux, centos, redhat, remote-access

We are planning to wipe our RHEL 5 HP ProLiant DL360p Gen8 server and put CentOS 6.4 on it. However, there are two major issues that may make the install different than normal:

- The server is in another state, I am going to have to use iLO virtual media as the installation DVD
- The server is totally blocked from the internet, I have VPN access into their network but that is the only way it can access the internet, is via any files I upload to it.

What concerns can I expect that would deviate from a normal wipe-and-install? For example, how can I use yum for updates and such when the server can't get on the internet?

Comment: Also, if this is the wrong Stack Exchange site, please tell me. Thanks!

Comment: Possibly duplicate of  [Update RHEL Servers without Internet Connection](http://serverfault.com/questions/218472/update-rhel-servers-without-internet-connection)?

Comment: @Cole While that is helpful, the target OS is CentOS, not RHEL

Comment: For the purposes of this question, there is no difference between RHEL and CentOS.

Comment: @John I agree with you, but the linked page talks about downloading isos from RHN etc.

Comment: @durron597: Then translate that to "download isos from ANL" or wherever. It's such a trivial difference that a systems admin should be able to translate on the fly in their head.

Answer (score 0):

There's probably a few different ways you can do this, it really all depends on how you want to go about it.

1. You could create a [local repo](http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/CreateLocalRepos) & [mirror](http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/CreateLocalMirror) for the CentOS 6.4 box.
2. Or you could also use [Kickstart](http://smorgasbork.com/component/content/article/35-linux/128-building-a-custom-centos-6-kickstart-disc-part-1) to create a custom image to do all the work for you. Kickstart would most likely be the most efficient way to do this, in my opinion. Especially if you already know what you want/need on the server.

Comment: I'm reading the Kickstart documentation... how would I get all the HP custom drivers to work properly? By drivers, [I mean these](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/SoftwareDescription.jsp?lang=en&cc=us&prodTypeId=15351&prodSeriesId=5177953&prodNameId=5177954&swEnvOID=4124&swLang=13&mode=2&taskId=135&swItem=MTX-b29b3088895742ae85b3398363)

Comment: @durron597 you can copy the rpms that are in the [tar.gz](http://i.imgur.com/IlsVD2G.png) file such as `~kickstart_build/all_rpms`