# RHEL 5.5 server has most devices listed as "Unknown Device"

Tags: redhat, installation, hp, hp-proliant, drivers

When I run `lspci` on my RHEL 5.5 Server (HP ProLiant DL360p Gen8), most items look like this:

```
00:03.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Unknown device 3c0b (rev 07)
00:04.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Unknown device 3c20 (rev 07)
.. snip ..
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Broadcom Corporation Unknown device 1657 (rev 01)
```

etc. of the 63 entries, 57 of them say Unknown device. **Note: I am not the person who originally purchased or set up this server, I am simply the person who has inherited it.** The prior adminstrator was fired (you know how that goes).

The server seems to be working fine, but I am planning to update to Centos 6.4 soon and I want to make sure I know the right hardware configuration.

Using `kudzu` and and [The PCI ID repository](http://pci-ids.ucw.cz/) I was able to figure out what most of the devices are; however, I was not able to locate the drivers for these devices. I would think that most of them would be compiled into the Kernel?

Here are some examples of things I discovered:

```
Intel Corporation Unknown device 1d00 (rev 05) <---> C600/X79 series chipset 4-Port SATA IDE Controller
Intel Corporation Unknown devices 3c02  <---> Xeon E5/Core i7 IIO PCI Express Root Port 1a
Intel Corporation Unknown devices 3c20  <---> Xeon E5/Core i7 DMA Channel 0
Hewlett-Packard Company Unknown device 323b <---> Compaq Smart Array Gen8 RAID Controller
```

However, my attempts to find real drivers (that don't say Unknown Device) have failed. I tried [intel's website](http://intel.com/), [HP's website](http://hp.com/), Red Hat and CentOS RPM mirrors, typing the names of these hardware identifiers into Google... all to no avail.

My questions:

1. Now that I know what these devices actually are, does it actually matter if I have the perfect drivers if nothing seems to be broken?

   - I don't know how to use `kudzu` very well. I was able to figure out to use `kudzu -s -p` but I want to be extra cautious I don't break anything.
2. What about when I do the OS reinstall, should I attempt to have the correct RPMs handy (if I can find them?) Or should the installation DVD know what to do and I don't have to worry about it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please refer to the [HP ProLiant RHEL Technical Exceptions Matrix](http://h18004.www1.hp.com/products/servers/linux/supportmatrix/rhel/exceptions/rhel-exceptions.html) entry for the [DL360p Gen8](http://h18000.www1.hp.com/products/quickspecs/productbulletin.html#spectype=north_america&type=html&docid=14211) server.

The minimum support version of RHEL5 on that server is 5.7. This is simply because the ProLiant Gen8 servers were released last year and the version of RHEL you have predates them.

[image]

It's not difficult to upgrade the server you have to RHEL 5.9, the current release as of this writing. That will bring you in line with support and take care of the issue you're writing about.

You don't need to download individual drivers for HP servers. The drivers are in the OS distribution and kernel drivers. You just need to use period-appropriate OS distributions...

---

As for your OS upgrade, I'm assuming you'll pursue a [fresh installation rather than an in-place upgrade](https://serverfault.com/questions/449048/why-is-it-so-difficult-to-upgrade-between-major-versions-of-red-hat-and-centos). Please install from a RHEL 6.4 DVD if you wish to avoid problems.

Post-installation, you can use the [HP Support Pack for ProLiant](http://h18004.www1.hp.com/products/servers/management/spp/index.html) or the newer [HP Software Delivery Repository](http://downloads.linux.hp.com) to pull down the management agents for the server via yum ([*starter guide here*](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bc/docs/support/SupportManual/c03479393/c03479393.pdf)). The management agents provide reporting and enhanced monitoring to the installation. The Support Pack bootable DVD will also upgrade the server's firmware (*incredibly important*).

Comment: Yes, I was planning to do a fresh installation. I want to go RAID 1+0, currently there is no RAID on the machine at all, so obviously I would need to do a fresh install for that. Of course, [I also have these problems...](http://serverfault.com/questions/524800/migrating-server-from-rhel-5-5-to-centos-6-4-remotely/524809?noredirect=1#comment597943_524809)

Comment: One other question; again, since this box is inherited, my RHEL license key status is sort of in Limbo (on reason for migrating to CentOS), I think I might have a problem using the 5.9 ISO without a proper license, I've never tried that before. But I suspect it's not worth the bother if the major install is in my future?

Comment: What's the disk layout right now? It's possible to convert RAID 0 to RAID 1+0 on HP controllers?

Comment: As for RHEL 5.9, you can upgrade the server using yum. There's no need for a DVD, as long as you have an entitlement and an internet connection. It's also possible to [convert the server to free CentOS](http://knowledgelayer.softlayer.com/procedure/convert-redhat-centos) if you don't wish to *buy* or renew your Red Hat license.

Comment: Haha, I just let my work desktop mirror the 6.4 repo all last night, I don't think I'm going to bother doing it again for 5.9. Especially since the 6.4 upgrade is soon. The disk layout is no RAID whatsoever, 4 identical HDs behind a Smart Array 420i. The partitions are kind of weird too, somehow most of the space is mounted as one drive.

Comment: Your path of least-resistance is to go to RHEL 5.9. This sounds like it's beyond the scope of this question, though.

Answer (score 2):

You're running an old OS on new hardware.

Since you have an old release of RHEL, you have an old version of the PCI ID database which is used to look up device IDs and give textual descriptions for them. And since it's old, it can't possibly have descriptions for hardware that didn't exist when it was created (since time travel does not yet exist).

This is not really an issue you need to worry about if you are updating to 6.4. It will have the latest PCI IDs and kernel drivers for any significant piece of hardware in that system. Anything that it might not have, such as HP management agents, you can obtain from HP.